# (Meteor) Change Twitter login button design

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How would you go about changing the deafult twitter login button that comes with `accounts-ui` to something more like [image]

Answer (score 0):

use acccouts-ui-unstyled instead of accounts-ui and custom CSS.

In my experience, it might be more hassle than it's worth though. I would recommend using the excellent [useraccounts](http://useraccounts.meteor.com/) package. It has predefined templates and helper for a few popular CSS frameworks and provides an actual template for login/signup/reset etc.

Comment: Where would the custom CSS go and how would I know what selectors to use? The documentation doesnt explain much lol

Comment: I'm afraid that as far as default accounts package is concerned, you have to manually look at the DOM and figure things out. The source is here if you are inclined so: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.html. As far as custom css go, you can put it anywhere in project_dir/client and meteor will include it for you.